# Add file-specific words to Sublime Text spell checking

Tags: sublimetext, spell-checking

If I use a certain (made-up) word only in a particular file. Is there a way to add it to the dictionary of **just that particular file** with Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 23 Jan 23**

Unfortunately not. You can use the [`added_words` setting](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/spell_checking.html) to include your special word in the dictionary:

```js
{
    // ...
    "added_words": [
        "Bandersnatch"
    ]
}
```

But this is an application-wide setting, and it's not consulted in the project or user setting scopes.

<strike>But if you put that in your [user settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/settings.html#settings-files), it will apply in all files. To be more precise, you can use [Projects](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/projects.html). Create a project file, then make sure you open your project using the Projects > Open Project… menu item. In there, you can put the `added_words` setting in the `settings` object:</strike>

```js
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "added_words": ["Bandersnatch"]
    },
}
```

This will apply the setting to just a single window, but it will be all files in that window. You can tailor the project (using the `folders` key) so that it only displays the one file, but that may be too restrictive.

Depending on the different file types you edit, it may be possible to tailor the [`spelling_selector`](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/settings.html#system-and-miscellaneous-settings) to uniquely identify this one file. In fact, if you wrote a syntax which applied a scope (which you could inherit from the real scope) to any file with the exact name your file has, then you'd be able to apply spelling only to that file using `spelling_selector`. However, I think this would turn off spelling for all other files, which is probably not what you want either.

Comment: You can in fact not add project-specific words: https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5775